# Set GridView PageSize from Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want to set the PageSize from a JQuery, the reson is that the gridView have a diffrent height on diffrent screens.

here is the Jquery i run on the page and the GridView

```
<script>
     //Initial load of page
     $(document).ready(sizePage);

     //Every resize of window
     $(window).resize(sizePage);

     //Dynamically assign height
     function sizePage() {
         var newHeight = $("#page").height() / 1.5;
         $("#mid").css("height", newHeight + "px");
         $("#box1").css("height", newHeight + "px");
         $("#box2").css("height", newHeight + "px");
         $("#field2").css("height", newHeight - 80 + "px");
         $('#<%= GridView.ClientID %>').attr("PageSize", "5");
     }
</script>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView" CssClass="tekst" Width="100%" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nyhed_overskrift" HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headcontent2" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nyhed_dato" HeaderText="Oprettet" HeaderStyle-Width="80" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headcontent2" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nyhed_id" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="invis" HeaderStyle-Width="0" ItemStyle-CssClass="invis" ItemStyle-Width="0" />
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="Image/Diverse/Arrow.png" CommandName="LaesNyhed" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" />
</Columns>
<PagerStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="tekst" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Well i dont get any error, but the line:
    $('#<%= GridView.ClientID %>').attr("PageSize", "5");
dont seem to have an effect, the GridView still have a PageSize of 10 as it is by default

Comment: I don't think you can do that for the gridview from your jquery code because when you set a new `PageSize` for gridview then binding has to happen like `GridView1.DataBind ();` which can be done only from code behind. Instead you can have the gridview within a `div` and set the height and scroll for the div from jquery depending on the screen where you are.

Comment: you may have a point as to the bind. I allready set the div height, but the problem is that the Gridview dont fill up with rows on big screens and there are to manny on small screens.
i can set the PageSize from Code behind, but then i need the newHeight attribute in the code behind, and i cant find a way to do that, any ideers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UpdatePanel with HiddenField to solve this issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Initial load of page
    $(document).ready(sizePage);

    //Every resize of window
    $(window).resize(sizePage);

    //Dynamically assign height
    function sizePage() {
        var newHeight = $("#page").height() / 1.5;
        $("#mid").css("height", newHeight + "px");
        $("#box1").css("height", newHeight + "px");
        $("#box2").css("height", newHeight + "px");
        $("#field2").css("height", newHeight - 80 + "px");
        //$('#<%= GridView.ClientID %>').attr("PageSize", "5");
        $('#<%= PageSizeHiddenField.ClientID %>').val('5'); //this is page size
        $('#<%= SetPageSizeButton.ClientID %>').click(); //async postback
    }
</script>
<script runat="server">
    protected void SetPageSize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView.PageSize = int.Parse(PageSizeHiddenField.Value);
        GridView.PageIndex = 0;
        GridView.DataBind();
        MyUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
</script>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="PageSizeHiddenField" />
<asp:Button ID="SetPageSizeButton" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="SetPageSize_Click" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="MyUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView" CssClass="tekst" Width="100%" runat="server" AllowPaging="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging"
            OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nyhed_overskrift" HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    HeaderStyle-CssClass="headcontent2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nyhed_dato" HeaderText="Oprettet" HeaderStyle-Width="80"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headcontent2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nyhed_id" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="invis"
                    HeaderStyle-Width="0" ItemStyle-CssClass="invis" ItemStyle-Width="0" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="Image/Diverse/Arrow.png" CommandName="LaesNyhed"
                    HeaderStyle-Width="50px" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="tekst" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SetPageSizeButton" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i had to change a few things to make it work, but your ideer got me going, and ill V you for that.